# PHP Split Array

Tags: php

I need to split an array but its not something I have done before.

The array is taken from a MySQL database by `mysql_fetch_array`:

Example:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Audi 
    [make] => Audi 
    [1] => 80 1.3 
    [model] => 80 1.3 
    [2] => 1297 
    [cc] => 1297 
    [3] => 1297 
    [choice] => 1297 
    [4] => 60 
    [bhp] => 60 
    [5] => 08/81-03/87 
    [date] => 08/81-03/87 
    [6] => EP 
    [engcode] => EP 
    [7] => Petrol 
    [fuel] => Petrol 
    [8] => - 
    [notes] => - 
    [9] => CAM BELT KIT 
    [type] => CAM BELT KIT 
    [10] => KTB201 
    [partno] => KTB201 
    [11] => AUDI 
    [itemspec] => AUDI
)
```

I need to change this to:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Audi 
    [1] => 80 1.3 
    [2] => 1297 
    [3] => 1297 
    [4] => 60 
    [5] => 08/81-03/87 
    [6] => EP 
    [7] => Petrol 
    [8] => - 
    [9] => CAM BELT KIT 
    [10] => KTB201 
    [11] => AUDI )
```

I have tried a few methods using filter array but I cannot seem to get it to output correctly, any ideas?

Comment: First lesson to learn (seriously): Read documentation and read it properly. Not every documentation is great but the PHP documentation is quite good.

Comment: Hi, Thank you all for your help, I start looking back at mysql_fetch_array after asking this question and found my answer. Sorry for the waste of the time and confusing question. I have been learning php only since Jan and all self taught. The hardest part I find is the terminology Thanks again to everyone who has taken the time to reply!!

Answer (score 8):

Use [the function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) properly in the first place instead of trying to fix the goof-up after.

Comment: Specifically: `mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM);`

Comment: I think it's clear that Ignacio wanted the OP to find this for himself in the documentation.

Comment: Hi, Thank you all for your help, I start looking back at mysql_fetch_array after asking this question and found my answer.

Sorry for the waste of the time and confusing question. I have been learning php only since Jan and all self taught. The hardest part I find is the terminology

Thanks again to everyone who has taken the time to reply!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
mysql_fetch_array ( $result, MYSQL_NUM );
```

It will return only numeric keys.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, those arrays are the same, it's just you have dropped the associative keys in favour of the numeric ones. What process can't you achieve without removing them?

The way I see it, you should be able to use the original array for the majority of processing purposes.

Comment: How are they the same? One has twice the number of elements as the other.

Comment: yeah, but in terms of actually using the array, it would be straight forward to process the first as if it where the second.

Answer (score 0):

try using mysql_fetch_row instead of mysql_fetch_array

references

http://nz.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php

http://nz.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array_unique`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) to keep only different elements from your array, but I'm not sure this is the better solution.

The "problem" is, according to [mysql_fetch_array documentation](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php), that the default fetch mode is `MYSQL_BOTH`, you should try using `MYSQL_NUM` :

```
$array = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM);
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you using `mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH)` statement. Change it to `mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)`

Answer (score 0):

[`mysql_fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) already has an option to only return numeric keys:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM);
```

Hope that helps.

<sup>(BTW, you wouldn't really call what you were asking "splitting" an array.)</sup>